How to handle touchpad scroll in nannou?
In my laptop, a touchpad scroll triggers events of type
MouseWheel(PixelDelta(PhysicalPosition(x, y)), Moved)

I can't find the struct PhysicalPosition in nannou and I try the one from std::winit - I get an error
expected `PhysicalPosition<f64>`, found a different `PhysicalPosition<f64>` 

How to handle touchpad scroll in nannou?
Minimal example:
    use nannou::prelude::{
        App, Frame, WindowEvent, WindowId, BLACK,
        MouseScrollDelta::LineDelta, MouseScrollDelta::PixelDelta, MouseWheel,
    };

    use winit::dpi::PhysicalPosition;
    
    fn main() { nannou::app(model).run(); }
    
    struct Model { _window: WindowId }
    
    fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
        let _window = app.new_window().view(view).event(event).build().unwrap();
        Model { _window }
    }
    
    fn view(app: &App, _model: &Model, frame: Frame) {
        frame.clear(BLACK);
        let draw = app.draw();
        draw.to_frame(app, &frame).unwrap();
    }
    
    fn event(_app: &App, _model: &mut Model, event: WindowEvent) {
        //println!("{:?}", event);
        match event {
            MouseWheel(LineDelta(x, y), ..) => { 
                println!("{event:?} - x,y: {x}, {y}");
            }
            MouseWheel(PixelDelta(PhysicalPosition::<f64>{ x, y }), ..) => {
                println!("{event:?} - x,y: {x}, {y}");
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }

Compile error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:28:24
    |
24  |     match event {
    |           ----- this expression has type `nannou::event::WindowEvent`
...
28  |         MouseWheel(PixelDelta(PhysicalPosition::<f64>{ x, y }), ..) => {
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `PhysicalPosition<f64>`, found a different `PhysicalPosition<f64>`

--- edit ---
Someone marked this question as a duplicate of this. The questions have nothing to do with each other :/
--- edit 2 ---
The duplicate mark hasn't been removed... Meanwhile I got awesome help using the Rust forum. Awesome community there.

What is the generic data type used for PhysicalPosition? Add the complete error message to your post.

@fdan post edited to include more complete error message

Compile error solved. Although not clear in the docs, it seems that nannou has a winit shipped in its dependencies, so just use this instead:
use nannou::winit::dpi::PhysicalPosition;

